# Wie bestimmt man eindeutig die Zählform eines Verbs?

Tags: verb, grammatical-number, verb-usage, list

Es sollte eigentlich eindeutig sein, worauf sich das Verb in den folgenden Sätzen jeweils bezieht und wie es demzufolge - Singular oder Plural - gebildet wird. Ist es (für mich) aber nicht.

Eigentlich ist in

> "Der Apfel, ebenso die Birne, **schmeckt** ihr gut."

das *ebenso die Birne* eingeschoben und wirkt sich nicht auf die Verbform von *schmecken* aus - oder?. Dennoch klingt das durchaus schon ein wenig komisch. Hingegen ist

> Der Apfel und ebenso die Birne **schmecken** ihr gut.

eindeutig, in diesen Fall handelt es sich um eine Aufzählung.

Aber was ist hiermit:

> Der Apfel - und ebenso die Birne - **schmeckt** ihr gut.

Die Gedankenstriche holen die Birne aus dem Satz heraus - oder? Aber würde *schmecken* nicht auch funktionieren?

Es wird noch schlimmer. In

> Der Apfel und nicht die Birne **schmeckt** ihr gut.

ist das Verbform vom Inhalt des Satzes abhängig. Die Negation macht klar, worauf sie das Verb bezieht. Schwächen wir diese aber ab mittels

> Der Apfel und vielleicht die Birne **schmecken** ihr gut.

kommt plötzlich wieder die Pluralform.

In meinen Hobby-Lektoratstätigkeiten für Freunde stoße ich immer wieder auf solche Konstruktionen. **Was ist die allgemeine Regel dafür** (wenn es denn eine gibt)?

**Update** - Bzgl. der mehrfachen Kritik, die Sätze seien in keinem typischen Muttersprachlerdeutsch formuliert ("fürchterlich konstruiert" plus Downvote), möchte ich auf den **Kontext der Frage** hinweisen.

Ich werde oft gebeten, **nicht-literarische Texte (Anträge, Aufsätze) gegenzulesen**, und da gibt es öfters holprige Formulierungen (durchaus viel, viel schlimmere als die mit dem Obst, die ich nicht immer verändern darf). **Dennoch möchte ich eine korrekte Grammatik verwenden**, und in diesem Rahmen halte ich die Frage einschl. der Beispiele für absolut angemessen.

Comment: Ich finde die Beispielsätze fürchterlich konstruiert. Welcher Muttersprachler sagt denn "Der Apfel, ebenso die Birne, ..."? Ich würde sagen, das Problem stellt sich für Muttersprachler nicht, weil die keine solchen Konstruktionen verwenden.

Comment: @Robert: Es sind doch nur Beispielsätze. Ich persönlich finde genau solche Konstruktionen auch schwierig. Daher schon mal +1 von mir und ich warte gespannt auf die Antworten ...

Comment: @Robert guter Punkt. Andererseits: Stell dir vor was Muttersprachler von den Sätzen halten würden die wir fabriziert haben als wir andere Sprach gelernt haben. Der Punkt ist ja eben Sätze und Konstrukte zu finden die die Grammatik ausreizen bzw. deren Beonderheiten zur Anwendung bringen.

Comment: @Olaf When "(und) ebenso die Birne" is kind of appendix it doesn't affect the verb. That is, when you make a break, add some aside information and then continue your sentence, the verb doesn't change. I consider your third and fifth example as wrong. "Der Apfel und ebenso die Birne schmecken ihr gut" - "Der Apfel–und vielleicht die Birne–schmeckt ihr gut." Still, not very likely to be said by a native. They would rather say: "Der Apfel schmeckt ihr gut–und vielleicht auch die Birne."

Comment: @Robert: Tatsächlich ist der diese Frage auslösende Originalsatz ein anderer, und vielleicht habe ich die Beispiele etwas hölzern gewählt, aber ich glaube nicht, dass dadurch der Sinn der Frage entstellt wird und dass man die weitreichende Folgerung ziehen kann, dass Muttersprachler keine solchen Konstruktionen verwenden. "Ihre Gefühlsarmut, ebenso ihre körperliche Schwäche, ließ sie..." war ungefähr das Original.

Comment: @Em1: then the question might be: when is the Birne part an appendix and then an enumeration?

Comment: @Olaf Mainly, that would be up to the speaker ;) – That said, you shouldn't use "und" for an appendix because "und" connects it too strongly. But when you take "und", you can weaken it by using some adverbs or particles.

Comment: @Em1 - "up to the speaker" means: you can use both?

Answer (score 2):

Simpel:

#### 2 Objekte => Plural

Auch die Birne im vorletzten Beispiel ("Der Apfel und nicht die Birne ...") schmeckt, d.h. bewirkt eine geschmackliche Wahrnehmung im Esser, bevor er sie für unschmackhaft befindet. Apfel *und* Birne schmecken also (nach etwas), auch wenn ihm die Birne dann nicht schmeckt.

Ich weiß die fachsprachlichen Termini nicht, aber "schmecken", wie du das Wort in deinen Beispielen verwendest, ist etwas, das dem Subjekt widerfährt. Er tut es nicht, sondern die Birne tut es mit ihm. Man könnte sagen, die Negation ("nicht") bezieht sich auf das Substantiv, nicht auf das Verb. Logisch könnte man formulieren: `(A und Nicht-B) schmecken ihm`. Anders wäre es mit einem Vorgang, den das Subjekt aktiv ausführt:

> Er schmeckt (d.h. probiert) den Apfel, die Birne aber schmeckt er nicht.

Hier wird das Verb negiert, insofern haben wir zwei Verben (im Singular) mit je einem eigenen Objekt.

**Achtung!**
a) `jmd. (Nom.-Subj.) schmeckt etwas (Akk.-Obj.)`
b) `etwas (Nom.-Subj.) schmeckt jmdm. (Dat.-Obj.)`

Richtig, bei den Beispielen in der Frage, ist jeweils die Variante mit Verb im Plural, weil der nicht von der Satzkonstruktion, sondern vom Verb und der Zahl der Objekte abhängt.

Comment: Schöne Ausführungen mit Anwendung boolescher Logik (A und Nicht-B) schmecken ihm. Allerdings finde ich in "Der Apfel, ebenso die Birne, schmeckt ihr gut." ein Plural schwierig, was sich bei einer einfachen Umstellung zeigt: "Der Apfel schmeckt ihr gut, ebenso die Birne." Ganz klar kein Plural, obwohl es sich um 2 Objekte handelt.